# Change orientation without setRequestedOrientation

Tags: java, android, android-activity, screen-orientation

When I click a button in my App, the screen orientation will automatically go to landscape :

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

The screen get to landscape successfully but it caused my `onConfigurationChanged` not working anymore.

I tried to use:  `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);` but it makes no difference.

What should I do, to make the screen go to landscape, when I click the button, without turning off the `onConfigurationChanged`?Or do you have any other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using API13 or higher as your target,
in your manifest you need to add `ScreenSize` to your `configChanges`:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks. But i want to change the screen when my button clicked

Comment: IF you add what I have posted to the manifest, and then you click your button - does it not work?